# configure socket.io to wss instead of ws

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, protocols

I am working on a small application that is hosted via `node.js` and uses `socket.io` for quick communication. For now it was only in development so it was fine. However now i would like to switch from `ws://` to `wss://` but dont really know where to start. I tried to research online but there is not much on the topic.

index.js (server)

```
const path = require("path");
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const cors = require("cors");
const config = require("./config");
const webRoute = require("./lib/routes/web");
const widgetsRoute = require("./lib/routes/widgets");
const errorsHandler = require("./lib/handlers/errors");
const corsHandler = require("./lib/handlers/cors");

app.use(cors(corsHandler));

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "/public")));

app.use("/", webRoute);
app.use("/widgets", widgetsRoute);

app.use(errorsHandler);

app.listen(4118, "0.0.0.0");

const io = require("socket.io").listen(
  require("http")
    .createServer()
    .listen(4113, "0.0.0.0")
);

require("./lib/inits/socket")(io);
```

client:

```
this.socket = io("http://example.org:4113");
```

In the network tab i can see that socket.io is using `ws://` in one of its calls.

How can i modify this so it uses `wss` instead?

Comment: Related "Is it possible to force socket.io to use wss instead of ws, without having to change to https" - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41426495/is-it-possible-to-force-socket-io-to-use-wss-instead-of-ws-without-having-to-ch

Comment: its not related, i dont want to force anything, i am asking how to configure socket.io to use wss, i saw this topic, there is nothing there to help me.

Comment: You are starting a client connection with `http` and not with `https` or even with `wss`, this is why I mentioned a related issue. When using `http` your client will most likely upgrade to using `ws` as far as I understand. BTW their documentation does not mention anything about `wss` or `https` which makes it quite confusing.

Comment: I found focumentation of `ws` module is clearer about how to set up `wss` https://github.com/websockets/ws#external-https-server

Comment: this is websockets, socket.io is not the same as websocket, if i was using native websocket there wouldnt be any problem.

Comment: Indeed, I do not disagree, but comparison puts this question in a clearer background. Still my argument about not using "https" or "wss" on the client stands.